# Is it possible to delete files from git objects?

Tags: git

Some large files were added to git repo and deleted in subsequent commits. Now I'm sending back and forth those MBs. Is there a way to get red from them in history commits or at least prevent loading them from the server?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/reduce-repository-size-321848262.html#Reducerepositorysize-Deletefilesbyname

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)